# Linear Equation (Problem with negative denominator)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is the problem

[image: This is the problem]      ||||

This is the beginning of the equation

[image: The beginning of the equation]

Hello, everyone! I wanted to ask how should I get rid of the negative sign in the denominator "-4x+3". I already know that I can type it as -3x-7/4x-3, but I don't know why the plus sign in front of 3 changes into a negative one. If someone can explain this I would appreciate it.

Comment: So the fraction you are starting out with is $\frac{3x+7}{-4x+3}$ and you don't want a negative sign in the denominator? If so, that's impossible. It's due to the distributive property of multiplication: $-(a+b)=-a-b$. So, that new fraction you have appears to come form the following: $\frac{3x+7}{-4x+3}=\frac{-1}{-1}\frac{3x+7}{-4x+3}=\frac{-(3x+7)}{-(-4x+3)}$, distribute in numerator and denominator: $\frac{-3x-7}{4x-3}$.

Comment: @c_gnar I am gonna edit and show you the starting of the problem. I just swap 3 with -4x and that's how -4x+3 appears. Because i want to make it so by multiplying everything with 4x+3 and 4x-3 the denominators to disappear and i was wondering what to do with that minus sign.. I tried everything even multiplying the whole equation by -1, but all i had to do is change from "-4x+3" to "4x-3" and that's why i couldn't understand why this is happening, but i know how to do it. I know that a/-b is -a/b and -(a/b) but I didn't know why the sign in the denominator changes after it was 3-4x (3>0 => +3)

Comment: That is simply because $ -4x+3=-(4x-3)$ by the rule of signs.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated!

Comment: What information was given to you, and what are you actually trying to do and why? Multiplying a fraction by $-1/-1$ isn't giving you what you want?

Comment: I'm not quite following you @vovid78065. If you multiply the right-hand side of the equation by $(-4x+3)(4x+3)$ then the denominators will fully cancel. If you multiply by $(4x-3)(4x+3)$ the denominators will still cancel but you will end up with a minus sign attached because $4x-3=-(3-4x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the size of the equation seems to have confused you. Just observe both equations:

The only difference is that instead of $3-4x$, $-4x+3$ is written. Isn't it?

In short, all you need is to realize that $$3-4x=-4x+3$$

$$\begin{align}3-4x
&=3+(-4x)\\
&=(-4x)+3\\
&=-4x+3.\end{align}$$